# How to open file on android with maui blazor app? File Chooser opens but files are disabled

Tags: c#, android, maui, maui-blazor

I used the [file-picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-picker?tabs=android) guide to show a file picker (code for reference at the bottom) in a maui blazor app.

On windows this works.

On android the file picker opens and shows but I can't click on any file since they are all disabled (grey text) and not clickable.

I already added `[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage)]` to the `MainApplication.cs` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

After installing the apk to my device or emulator I granted the storage permission (since I haven't implemented a dialog yet).

How can I open files on an android device with a maui app?

---

- Visual Studio 2022 (latest update)
- .NET Core 6

```
<button @ref="button1" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OpenFileAsync">Open File</button>

@code {
    public async void OpenFileAsync()
    {
        var customFileType = new FilePickerFileType(
                new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                    { DevicePlatform.iOS, new[] { "public.my.comic.extension" } }, // or general UTType values
                    { DevicePlatform.Android, new[] { "application/comics" } },
                    { DevicePlatform.WinUI, new[] { ".cbr", ".cbz" } },
                    { DevicePlatform.Tizen, new[] { "*/*" } },
                    { DevicePlatform.macOS, new[] { "cbr", "cbz" } }, // or general UTType values
                });

        PickOptions options = new()
        {
            PickerTitle = "Please select a comic file",
            FileTypes = customFileType,
        };

        var result = await FilePicker.Default.PickAsync(options);
        // ... process result
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the accepted file types based on the platform your using.. for e.g on your code:
`{ DevicePlatform.Android, new[] { "application/comics" }`

The accepted file extention types are 'application/comics'. if you want for the image to be enabled change/add a new type to the list.

`{ DevicePlatform.Android, new[] { "application/comics","image/*" }`